# skipping unknown number of lines to read the header python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have an excel data that i read in with python pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('..../file.txt', sep='\t' )
```

the mock data looks like this:

```
unwantedjunkline1
unwantedjunkline2
unwantedjunkline3
 ID     ColumnA     ColumnB     ColumnC
 1         A          B            C
 2         A          B            C
 3         A          B            C
...
```

the data in this case contains 3 junk lines(lines i don't want to read in) before hitting the header and sometimes it contains 4 or more suck junk lines. so in this case i read in the data :

```
data = pd.read_csv('..../file.txt', sep='\t', skiprows = 3 )
```

data looks like:

```
 ID     ColumnA     ColumnB     ColumnC
 1         A          B            C
 2         A          B            C
 3         A          B            C
...
```

**But each time the number of unwanted lines is different**, is there a way to read in  a table file using pandas without using 'skiprows=' but instead using some command that matches the header so it knows to start reading from the header? so I don't have to click open the file to count how many unwanted lines the file contains each time and then manually change the 'skiprows=' option.

Comment: Just skip the lines yourself and pass a file object

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham  sorry?  i don't follow

Comment: use `open` to have a file object, iterate through your file object until you reached the end of your junk (you'll have to find out how to assess this) then pass the file object into `pd.read_csv(fileobject, ..)` instead of your filepath.

Comment: @Jessica, I added an answer, once you know the header then you just pass that to the function,   the logic with readline and tell is all that is important, you can do whatever you want with it i.e take more args or just use the logic, it is just an example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know what the header startswith:

```
def skip_to(fle, line,**kwargs):
    if os.stat(fle).st_size == 0:
        raise ValueError("File is empty")
    with open(fle) as f:
        pos = 0
        cur_line = f.readline()
        while not cur_line.startswith(line):
            pos = f.tell()
            cur_line = f.readline()
        f.seek(pos)
        return pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs)
```

Demo:

```
In [18]: cat test.txt
1,2
3,4
The,header
foo,bar
foobar,foo
In [19]: df = skip_to("test.txt","The,header", sep=",")

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
      The header
0     foo    bar
1  foobar    foo
```

By calling `.tell` we keep track of where the pointer is for the previous line so when we hit the header we seek back to that line and just pass the file object to pandas.

Or using the  junk if they all started with something in common:

```
def skip_to(fle, junk,**kwargs):
    if os.stat(fle).st_size == 0:
        raise ValueError("File is empty")
    with open(fle) as f:
        pos = 0
        cur_line = f.readline()
        while cur_line.startswith(junk):
            pos = f.tell()
            cur_line = f.readline()
        f.seek(pos)
        return pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs)

 df = skip_to("test.txt", "junk",sep="\t")
```

Comment: @Jessica,  because you need to pass `sep="\t"`, I added an option to pass  keywords that will be passed to read_csv, I also misses a `not` with my edit ;0

Comment: how to change this function to output excel file instead of .csv? I tried but the error i keep getting is:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 17: character maps to <undefined> ,  when applying it to read excel file.

Comment: @Jessica, set `encoding="utf8"` in thw open call

Comment: i tried 'encoding='latin-1' no error messages but no output either, the script seems to be running forever.   @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @Jessica, you need to specify the correct encoding or you could end up with garbage, do you know the actual encoding that the data was encoded to? Also, as far as running forever goes, if your file is very large, it could take quite a while to parse, there is no way the while loop never ends as it stops on a match or the EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to achieve a dynamic skiprows would something like this which worked for me:

```
# Open the file
with open('test.csv', encoding='utf-8') as readfile:
        ls_readfile = readfile.readlines()
        
        #Find the skiprows number with ID as the startswith
        skip = next(filter(lambda x: x[1].startswith('ID'), enumerate(ls_readfile)))[0]
        print(skip)

#import the file with the separator \t
df = pd.read_csv(r'test.txt', skiprows=skip, sep ='\t')
```