# How to ignore junk data while extracting data from text file to pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have [url](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/PERMIT.txt) which contains a text file which I want to load into pandas dataframe. But there is some metadata at the top which I am not able to skip while parsing and it returns error.

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

This is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/PERMIT.txt')
```

This code usually works for me when there is no metadata at the top. How do I skip the meta data while loading?

The beginning of the `txt` file looks like:

```
Title:               New Private Housing Units Authorized by Building Permits
Series ID:           PERMIT
Source:              U.S. Bureau of the Census, U.S. Department of Housing and Urban Development
Release:             New Residential Construction
Seasonal Adjustment: Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate
Frequency:           Monthly
Units:               Thousands of Units
Date Range:          1960-01-01 to 2018-03-01
Last Updated:        2018-04-24 7:01 AM CDT
Notes:               Starting with the 2005-02-16 release, the series reflects an increase
                     in the universe of permit-issuing places from 19,000 to 20,000 places.

DATE        VALUE
1960-01-01   1092
1960-02-01   1088
1960-03-01    955
1960-04-01   1016
1960-05-01   1052
1960-06-01    958
1960-07-01    999
1960-08-01    994
```

Comment: if you know how many rows, you can use the parameter `skiprows ` of `read_csv()`, check the [documentations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Can you show some of text file.

Comment: The link is available in (url) highlighted above.

Comment: I added the beginning of your `txt` file to the body of your question, makes the question easier to address for people helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`skiprows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) argument to skip your metadata. In your case, you have 12 rows:

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/PERMIT.txt', skiprows=12, sep='\s+')
>>> data.head()
   DATE        VALUE
0  1960-01-01   1092
1  1960-02-01   1088
2  1960-03-01    955
3  1960-04-01   1016
4  1960-05-01   1052
```

Alternatively, tell `read_csv` where the header is with the `header` argument (row 11):

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/PERMIT.txt', header=11, sep='\s+')
>>> data.head()
   DATE        VALUE
0  1960-01-01   1092
1  1960-02-01   1088
2  1960-03-01    955
3  1960-04-01   1016
4  1960-05-01   1052
```

If you don't know how many lines to skip, you could implement the strategy used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34028755/6671176)

Comment: The two columns come fused together with only some blank space between. Are you getting them separately as 2 columns?

Comment: Indeed, see my edit. The issue is that your `txt` file is delimited by a variable amount of whitespace, so add the `sep` argument as shown

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to preserve the header:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.common import StringIO as sio
import requests as req

url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/PERMIT.txt'
res = req.request('get', url).content.decode()

h, b = res.replace('\r', '').split('\n\n')

s = pd.read_fwf(
    sio(h.replace(':', '')),
    header=None,
    names=['key', 'value']
).ffill().groupby('key').value.apply('\n'.join)

df = pd.read_csv(sio(b), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then see our handy work

```
print(s.head(), df.head(), sep='\n\n')

key
Date Range                               1960-01-01 to 2018-03-01
Frequency                                                 Monthly
Last Updated                                2018-04-24 701 AM CDT
Notes           Starting with the 2005-02-16 release, the seri...
Release                              New Residential Construction
Name: value, dtype: object

         DATE  VALUE
0  1960-01-01   1092
1  1960-02-01   1088
2  1960-03-01    955
3  1960-04-01   1016
4  1960-05-01   1052
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: oh, no 2.7. Let me try with python 3.

Comment: It's just a print statement.  You can print to see it any way you choose.