# How to read bunch of excel file in python/pandas with keyword starting columnnames

Tags: python, pandas

I have bunch  of excel files where data starts at random rows beyond first row in a sheet
.
There is no pattern to starting row number but the column names are constant. For example in a file I have columns PolicyNumber, AccountValue in row 3 and in another its in row 5 and in another its row 10.

I need to extract the data for these column in the files in python. How could I accomplish that with xlsx file format.

Comment: i had similar question before, see my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028511/skipping-unknown-number-of-lines-to-read-the-header-python-pandas

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]