# How to skip/delete rows up until a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I am reading in this csv from a url (https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/). My question is how to skip all rows up to the string "Available Weeklys - Exchange Traded Products (ETFs and ETNs)". It is not as simple, however, as skiprows=15. I can not simply skip a certain number of rows because the number of rows before the string is subject to change in the future so I need to use the string as the stopping point. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe: [skipping unknown number of lines to read the header python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028511/skipping-unknown-number-of-lines-to-read-the-header-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could read the contents of the file into a string, count the number of newlines until your search string is encountered and use this count to skip the required number of lines dynamically.

```
import requests

# read contents of link into string variable
link = 'https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/'
output = requests.get(link).text


find_str = "Available Weeklys - Exchange Traded Products (ETFs and ETNs)"
# find index of search string in output
idx = output.find(find_str)
# Count number of newlines until search string is encountered
skiprows_val = output[:idx+len(find_str)].count("\n")
print(skiprows_val)

df = pd.read_csv(link, skiprows = skiprows_val)
df
```